# How To Use Different Strategy Which Dependent To Activate Profile To Generate The Id In Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have A Question.

I have a Spring Boot Application. It has Tree Application Profiles, Main  (application.yml), Development (application-h2.yml) And Production (application-oracle.yml) File/Profile.  I Have JPA Entities In My Project. How Can I Say, If I Want To Work With/On Oracle Use Please This GeneradValue See The Screenshot. And When I Will Work With/On H2 Database Use Please This GeneratedValue See The Screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajyP3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't the `@GenericGenerator` impl you provide act as a delegate based on a system property? Let's say you read the profile VM arg in the implementation and routes / delegates to `h2` or `Oracle`.

You would keep the `REPORT_ID_GEN` generated value annotation and the strategy implementation would take care of deciding if using `H2` or `Oracle` instead of including 2 `@GeneratedValue` annotations.